# UTC file is not opening

Tags: mist

My downloaded UTC file not opened due to not support any program for view or open. this file is without extension name. 
How to open this file and please suggest in which extension will support. 
without support of UTC file I will transfer fund/ETH to another wallet or not? please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open it. Just add it to your keystore located under %appdata%/ethereum/keystore.

Answer (score 0):

It is a plain text file containing your private key encrypted by a passphrase. You can open it in any text editor, but I doubt it will help. If you are using Mist, you should put that file inside `./ethereum/keystore` (or wherever your `--chaindata` is) and Mist will recognize it as an account, which you can send a transaction from just by entering your passphrase.